# Error Swift Programming How to search an Array of [Any]--> Generic parameter 'C.Generator.Element' cannot be bound to non-@ob

Tags: arrays, swift

Hi I'm trying to search an array with various objects though I'm getting an error.

> Generic parameter 'C.Generator.Element' cannot be bound to non-@ob

Here is my code I'm using:

```
var arraySearching = [Any]()
arraySearching = ["this","that",2]
find(arraySearching, 2)
```

How do you search arrays of type `[Any]`?

Comment: Why don't you just use the jquery for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a misleading error message, but the problem is that `find` requires that the contents of the collection you are searching be `Equatable`, and `Any` isn’t.  You can’t do much with `Any` at all in fact, never mind equate it with values of other types.  You have to cast it to a real type and then use that.

That’d be easy to do in a closure, except there isn’t a version of `find` that takes a closure.  But it’s easy to write one:

```
func find<C: CollectionType>(source: C, match: C.Generator.Element -> Bool) -> C.Index? {
    for idx in indices(source) {
        if match(source[idx]) { return idx }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Once you have this, you can use it to search for a value of a specific type in an array of `Any`:

```
find(arraySearching) { 
    // cast the candidate to an Int, then compare (comparing an
    // optional result of as? works fine, nil == 2 is false)
    ($0 as? Int) == 2 
}
```

Comment: So search the same array I would have to adjust  ($0 as? String) == "this"if I were to search for the string? Is there anyway to make it so that the search will accept anyobject as well?

Comment: Yup that would be the string equivalent. This code should work for `AnyObject` as well or any other type where you can write a working `match` closure expression that returns true for a match.